# Load xml using XDocument.Load error "root element is missing" from stream

Tags: c#, stream, linq-to-xml

I got problems in using XDocument.Load because sometimes there is no error and sometimes there is already error, same error "root element is missing" I already tried using seek and position still the same error occurs.

Any ideas how can I fix this issue? Thanks

Here is my source code so far:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //stream.Position = 0;
            var request = XDocument.Load(stream);
            var get_command = from r in request.Descendants("Transaction")
                              select new
                              {
                                  Type = r.Element("Type").Value
                              };

            foreach (var c in get_command)
            {
                type = c.Type;
            }
        }
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request>
  <Transaction>
    <Type>gc</Type>
  </Transaction>
</Request>
```

Comment: How does XML look like?

Comment: @L-Three, Updated, I think there is no problem with the xml because sometimes it gives no error. and sometimes gives the same error

Comment: Why don't you use XDocument.Load(filePath) instead?

Comment: @cheol.lui: Is that *actually* sample XML, or is that just a radically simplified version? Does that exact file fail in the same way?

Comment: @L-Three, i tried that already but it willsays cannot access the file because its being used by another process

Comment: @JonSkeetm that the exact file sir

Comment: I think you should find out what process is using the file.

Comment: If another process is using the file that is your clue - I bet it is being updated while you are trying to read from it. Hence it sometimes fails (update/rewrite from other process incomplete) and succeeds at other time (update/rewrite from other process completed)

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be your sample is over simplified and your Xml looks more like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request>
  <Transaction>
    <Type>gc</Type>
  </Transaction>
</Request>
<Request>
  <Transaction>
    <Type>gc</Type>
  </Transaction>
</Request>
```

That would explain your error as there is no root element. You need to make it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Requests>
  <Request>
    <Transaction>
      <Type>gc</Type>
    </Transaction>
  </Request>
  <Request>
    <Transaction>
      <Type>gc</Type>
    </Transaction>
  </Request>
</Requests>
```